# How to run sudo command on host machine from Docker container without --privileged

Tags: docker, networking, docker-network

I have a docker container making changes to host network. Modifying ip tables works fine:

```
docker run --net=host --cap-add=NET_ADMIN myimage
```

Problem is I need to flush the route cache on host machine from the container:

```
/sbin/ip route flush cache
```

Which fails with the output:

> can't open '/proc/sys/net/ipv4/route/flush': Read-only file system

This is expected, since

```
user@ubuntu-virtual:~$ ll /proc/sys/net/ipv4/route/flush
--w------- 1 root root 0 Sep  5 10:11 /proc/sys/net/ipv4/route/flush
```

I would rather avoid using --privileged mode for security issues. Is there any workaround to execute only this single command with privileges?

Comment: The container root user isn't the actual root user which is associated with those files. Wouldn't it be a better option to run this through the host instead and keep the container secure with its pseudo-root?

Comment: The whole point of Docker is that you can’t do this.  Run the process on the host as root, if you need to make system-wide administrator-level changes.

Comment: I understand your points. The only exception is this single command for flushing the routing table. I was hoping to find a workaround for this single command only, since the whole setup works.